Getting two copies of the JS files for my LWC component in Chrome
I'm trying to use Chrome local overrides to make debugging JS quicker.  But I'm getting two versions of the JS file in my Chrome sources panel.
I created a new LWC named 'Hello World'.  On the first load, there's one copy, and I can use Chrome overrides as expected.  However, on the second load, there's another copy with a different path and my overridden changes don't work.  Here are the two paths:
https://connect-flow-485-dev-ed.scratch.lightning.force.com/components/c/helloWorld.js
https://connect-flow-485-dev-ed.scratch.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Account/001O100000OsFayIAF/modules/c/helloWorld.js
They have different content but both have the "meat" of the component as expected.  I can override both but only the overrides in one will take effect.  Similarly, only breakpoints in one will stop execution.  It seems like a caching issue but I have Disable Cache checked on the Network panel.
(https://i.sstatic.net/19IsdcU3.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/M6Pgrm4p.png)
